# Using apt-get partially through a proxy server

Tags: apt, proxy

My University Campus has Ubuntu Repos on the Local Server.

Also, we use a proxy server to connect to the Internet.

Now, my Repository is the Campus Local Server, but I do have a lot PPAs installed in my system.

When I do `apt-get update` through the Proxy Server, even the connections to the Local Server go via the Proxy Server, making the whole process very slow.

If I don't use the Proxy Server, then the PPAs don't get updated.

How can I do `apt-get update`, such that only PPAs use the Proxy Server, and the other Repos get updated directly from the Local Server without going through the Proxy Server.

Comment: Contact your system admin in Campus and tell to add PPA deatails to server or other way is make such adjustment to connect ISP without proxy only for you.

Comment: The sysadmins in the Institute are not very flexible. They won't make changes for individual users. So, making changes in the server side is out of the question. I just would like to know if something can be done from my side. I am sure this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense - Disable proxy and `update-upgrade` to get the repository upgrades, and then enable proxy for the PPAs - you can script this by using the `$http_proxy` env var.

Edit: this method is still not good enough. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17716/transparent-local-proxy-to-many-proxies) 
suggests another idea. Perhaps you can setup a proxy of your own locally, and that proxy can redirect to the university for all URLs except for your local server.

Comment: What do you mean by update-upgrade?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: But once I enable proxy, the repository gets updated once again.

Comment: hmm yes, this method would finish the upgrades using a direct connection, but update would still be slow.. let me think more